# Incorrect spacing between theorems when a figure is between them

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, floats, amsthm

I have a document with two theorems one after the other. The first theorem has a diagram to explain something. My MWE is like this.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\captionsetup{tableposition=top,figureposition=bottom,font=small}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{figure}[tp]
        \centering
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (p1) at (0, 0) {\(P_1\)};
            \node (p2) [right = of p1] {\(P_2\)};
            
            \draw[->] (p1) to [bend left = 30] (p2);
            \draw[->] (p2) to [bend left = 30] (p1);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        
        \caption{Diagram of what should happen in the first theorem.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{theorem}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

The result has a problem: the spacing between the two theorems is almost twice as normal.
[image: Incorrect spacing with figure]

If I remove the `figure` environment completely, the spacing is normal. [image: Correct spacing]

What can I do to avoid this unnecessary spacing?

Comment: What happens if you insert the instruction `\raggedbottom` in the preamble?

Comment: @Mico Nothing changes. The spacing remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially what you see can be summarized by this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
First line
\vskip 5pt

% \begin{figure}\end{figure}

\vskip 5pt
Second line
\end{document}
```

The problem here is that the `figure` environment is not entirely transparent to the skips and LaTeX can no longer collapse the consecutive skips.  The solution is therefore to place the figure inside the theorem environment.

```
\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{figure}
    ...
  \end{figure}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: This works. If there is no other way to avoid the double skip, I'm using this solution